# Control who uses iOS enterprise app using enterprise distribution provisioning profile?

Tags: iphone, ios, profile, provisioning, restrict

If I subscribe to the iOS Developer Enterprise Program, and want to restrict use of an app to specific individuals' devices, can I use an enterprise distribution provisioning profile to nominate the allowed device IDs? ... in a similar way to ad-hoc beta testing where up to 100 nominated device IDs can be specified.

[This Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html) says 'Next, you need to create an enterprise distribution provisioning profile so your users can use your app on their device' but leaves the question open.

I expect that restricting access to the provisioning profile itself would not be sufficient since one user could pass it on to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot restrict the app installation to few devices. It is designed to support Enterprise model to let them install on any iOS device given app supports the hardware/software.
Enterprise Program is not for an Individual, you need to provide them your Company's DUNS number and contact from Legal department. Typically we host all Over-the-air-distribution apps on internal website.

*This Apple doc says 'Next, you need to create an enterprise distribution provisioning profile so your users can use your app on their device' but leaves the question open.
 I expect that restricting access to the provisioning profile itself would not be sufficient since one user could pass it on to another.*

What good is provisioning profile by itself ? For apps (ipa) signed with in-house certificate have provisioning profile embedded inside the app and the devices don't need to install provisioning profile first like in other cases ( Dev, adHoc). When users install inhouse app provisioning profile installs automatically.